# Compose Text Field strange behaviour when setting a max length for text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I am trying to set a limit for the max characters count in a TextField.
This is what I tried:

```kotlin
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val maxLength = 40
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it.take(maxLength)
    }
)
```

Here's the problem:

- When I exceed the limit, the entire text suddenly gets cleared.
- This happens only once i.e. when I retype and exceed limit it just stops there (which is the desired behavior)
- 40 seems like a magic number here, because for maxLength = 39 or lower, everything works fine. When I set the limit to 40 or higher, I see this strange behavior. (This magic number doesn't seem to depend upon text field width as I experimented with both portrait and landscape mode and the result was same)

How to get rid of this behavior? What's the right way to set a max length for TextField text?

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine to me. You've probably faced a Compose bug, [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) it to Compose issue tracker including the version of Android you're using, Compose version and the device model.

Comment: Looks like that's the case here. I tried this code on my emulator and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use take() to limit the number of strings.

take() only means to take the first number of strings.

You can consider the string itself, and just judge the number of strings so that it does not exceed 40.

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val maxLength = 40
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.length <= 40)
          text = it
    }
)
```

Comment: This isn't working as well. Shows the same behavior.

Comment: What does the resulting behavior look like?

Comment: Same as that in the attached gif.

Comment: It may be related to height and width, I am not sure about this.

Comment: Looks like it is related to device type. I tried running it on emulator and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this bug doesn't occur on Android 12, where on 11 and lower it does.

Fortunately, according to Google Issue Tracker, that was a TextField bug that it is already fixed in Jetpack Compose `1.2.0-alpha04`.

See related topics [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193896392) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220161117).